# Minor problem in CSS overlapping

Tags: bug, status-declined, stack-overflow, design

I noticed that recently there seemed to some be problems with the stylesheet of the Stack Overflow, see the following figure:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tested on Ubuntu 13.10 with Chrome/Firefox Latest, these overlapping, especially in the comments, might cause unreadability.

**EDIT**

Yes, I changed Chrome font size to large instead of medium.  But I think a good css should work well regardless of the font size?

**Reproducing the problem**:

Please visit this post: [Mode of Array C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920768/mode-of-array-c)

Click `show 7 more comments`, and try changing the font size to larger one, you will see the overlapping texts

I think this might be font size unit issue, see a [detailed discussion](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/)

Comment: Is this just on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Your font size looks larger than normal. Are you zoomed in or something?

Comment: @AlEverett I forgot to mention, I discover this on stackoverflow.  But  it seems to exist on meta-stackoverflow

Comment: @animuson I set the chrome font to large instead of medium. This is the crux of the problem.  I thought the css should work well in 16px font or 14px font.

Comment: AFAIK that's a Chrome bug where it doesn't properly resize the containers when it changes the font-size via that setting. If you manually edited the CSS itself to be 16px, you would not experience any overlapping problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behavior. I tried and it just clips the text because it's too large for the box. No overlapping.

Comment: @animuson I'm afraid not.  The problem still exist.

Comment: @animuson please see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920768/mode-of-array-c/19920909#19920909  When you click `show 7 more comments` to my post, try changing the size of the font.  You will see overlapping

Comment: With these types of posts,  you need alot of details. versions, clear screen-shots, reproducibility etc . otherwise we cant help you much

Comment: @downvoter  This is not a problem?  So we just ignore it and everyone should use the same font size in order to get a clear text view?

Comment: To be fair, I was the upvoter...

Comment: @Adel Thanks :) I just thought this might be an improvement.

Comment: Why `em`s is the best unit.

Comment: @minitech Yes, `%` also works I think :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't support changing the font size, it's not a reasonable thing to design around.  Every modern browser has full page zoom for accessibility now, and it's the proper thing to use.

If you change just the font size it breaks layouts all across the web (and on your OS for that matter).  It's just not something we'll ever support...not when there's such a readily available much better supported alternative.

Comment: well that makes sense.  Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: I'm really surprised by this answer (not a personal attack, Nick). I hope that's not the official position of the Stack Exchange network. I've worked with two visually impaired people, and they need the assistance. Claiming you won't investigate it or fix it because it breaks layout seems callous at best.

Comment: @noloader visually impaired people can zoom the entire page, available in every modern browser and something we fully support.  Zooming *pieces* of a page we can't really reasonable support in any number of scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that most websites will display similar behavior when you play with the font-size, or zoom in on the text only. The obvious solution would be not to do that, zoom in on the entire page instead.

Zoom text only:

[image]

Zoom entire page:

[image]

Comment: I agree.  But I think this is a design issue.  At least with css we could achieve non-overlapping for font size in a reasonable range.